# Getting data from "Control" type to store assortment of other Controls (CheckBox/TextBox/NumericUpDown etc)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a type that contains a few strings and a generic control. My problem is that I don't know how to access the data that is stored inside the control.

Basically my program loops through some "custom types" which have _control "Children" which are then assigned to New CheckBox or other form controls.

```
private Control _control { get; set; }
public void set_control(Control control) { this._control = control; }
```

elsewhere

```
x.set_control(new CheckBox
                  {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    AutoSize = false,
                    Text = x.name(),
                    Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(x.data())
                  });
x.control().Click += delegate { refresh_data(x); };
```

pseudo code

```
private void refresh_data(embedded_setting setting)
{
  if (setting.control().GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
  {
    setting.set_data(setting.control());
  }
}
```

I need to set_data to control.checked.tostring. But I'm not sure how to use the control type as if its a checkbox type.

I'm hoping it can be carried over to be used with TextBox.Text and NumericUpDown.Value as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but after checking:

```
control.getType() == typeof(CheckBox)
```

You can cast the control as a checkbox like so:

```
((CheckBox)control).Checked
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. I was unaware of the terminology to properly ask the question =) Now I know that what I was looking for was how to cast a type.

Answer (score 0):

To check if your control is a Checkbox, you can use **is** to validate it.

```
 if(controlVariable is CheckBox)
 {
     var checkBox = controlVariable as Checkbox;    
      // then you can use checkBox variable to access it's properties.
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried something like this but I kept getting syntax errors. Although I am curious if this method of comparing the control type, is faster then the way I was doing it?